# Android Studio 3.5 ignores Keep Order for Android namespace attributes

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.5

After updating to Android Studio 3.5 all of the Android namespace attributes in the XML layout editor seem to be getting reordered by name even though `Keep Order` is set.

I reset my Project's code style settings from the predefined Android setting and it still doesn't do anything.

```
<codeStyleSettings language="XML">
      <indentOptions>
        <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
      </indentOptions>
      <arrangement>
        <rules>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>xmlns:android</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>xmlns:.*</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
              <order>BY_NAME</order>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>.*:id</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>.*:name</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>name</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>style</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>.*</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>^$</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
              <order>BY_NAME</order>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>.*</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
              <order>ANDROID_ATTRIBUTE_ORDER</order>
            </rule>
          </section>
          <section>
            <rule>
              <match>
                <AND>
                  <NAME>.*</NAME>
                  <XML_ATTRIBUTE />
                  <XML_NAMESPACE>.*</XML_NAMESPACE>
                </AND>
              </match>
              <order>BY_NAME</order>
            </rule>
          </section>
        </rules>
      </arrangement>
    </codeStyleSettings>
```

As you can see `ANDROID_ATTRIBUTE_ORDER` is set for any attributes in the Android namespace. Removing that doesn't make a difference. Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/57608288/2000323

Comment: @Andrey it looks like a bug with the new Android Studio. After a restart it resolved itself.